# ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged is not raised

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a form that only contains an empty ComboBox.
I set the DataSource to an empty BindingList.
When I add something to the BindingList, it is selected and combobox1.SelectedIndex changes, but the event comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged is not raised even tough it should in my opinion. Why is it not raised? When the single item is removed, the comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged is fired correctly.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        var test_ = new BindingList<int>();
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.DataSource = test_;
        Console.WriteLine(comboBox1.SelectedIndex); // -1
        test_.Add(42); // BUG? no comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged -> 0
        Console.WriteLine(comboBox1.SelectedIndex); // 0
        test_.Remove(42); // comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged -> -1
        Console.WriteLine(comboBox1.SelectedIndex); // -1
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("index changed " + comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not correct with your logic.

`comboBox1.SelectedIndex` is `-1` doesn't mean that you have an `item` selected in `-1` position!
It means there is no item selected in `comboBox1`.

Adding an item, the `SelectedIndex` becomes `0`. No **change** on the selection has happened because there was **no item** been selected in the first place *(SelectedIndex = -1)*.

Comment: You sure? I get an event when the state changes from "item 0 selected" to "no item selected", so shouldn't the reverse action also raise the event?

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around the bug is to tap into the ListChanged event of the BindingList collection you are using:

```
var test_ = new BindingList<int>();
comboBox1.DataSource = test_;
test_.ListChanged += (sender, e) => {
  if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemAdded && test_.Count == 1) {
    comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(comboBox1, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
};
test_.Add(42);
```